# Are e-cigarettes any good if you have asthma?

Tags: smoking, asthma, safety, asthma-attack, e-cigarette-vape

I have ashtma. From my experience, smoking kills my lungs. After a few weeks, I simply **have** to stop, or otherwise I got such bad coughs that I have to puke sometimes. Though, my asthma is not there while I don't smoke. During a non-smoking period, I don't have to use any asthma medicine a week after I stopped!

But then I'll start smoking again due to the nicotine addiction, obviously.

Just recently I switched to **vaping e-cigarettes** instead of smoking. I managed to quit smoking tobacco this way.

**Does vaping e-cigarettes cause asthma attacks, or is it safer or maybe entirely safe for me?**

Comment: Asthma is always present, even if you don't feel any symptoms. You only get the symptoms when the airways narrow due to some trigger, but the system inflammation of the airways is actually always present. This can only change on very long time scales. Medications can reduce this inflammation. This is why it is unwise to attribute changes in symptoms to the asthma becoming better or worse and  modify the medication on the basis of that.